# ScrollView shows smudge at the bottom of the frame when scrolling the items

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, border, frame

I am using the GridItems inside the ScrollView to show ten circles horizontally. It works fine but there are lines of smudge shown at the bottom border line of ScrollView container. I tried,

1. Addind padding to ScrollView.
2. Adding padding to HStack.

Any recommendations would be appreciated! I captured the screenshot scrolling all the way to the left and beyond holding the press.

Using iPhone 13 mini simulator,
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYQDm.png)

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView.init([.vertical]) {
            Section(header: Text("Today's Items").font(.system(size: 20.0, weight:.semibold, design: .rounded))) {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(spacing: 10) {
                        ForEach(0..<20) { _ in
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color.random)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        }
                    }.padding(.vertical).background(.blue)
                }.padding(.vertical).background(.orange)
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: With help from Yrb, I verified that I only see this in iPhone 12 and 13 mini simulators only (with 13 device being worse). But I don't own either model physically. If anybody can test it on the physical devices and share the observation I would appreciate it.

Comment: I am not seeing it at all on the simulator, even at 150%. How are you previewing it?

Comment: Really? I am using Xcode iPhone 13 mini simulator. Not the phone.

Comment: Okay, it shows on the iPhone mini 13 simulator, but not on the pro. Did you try it on a real device? It may simply be an issue with the 13 mini simulator.

Comment: No, I do not. But if it's an issue with the simulator only then I guess I can move on. Or at least not worry too much about it for now. Thanks

Comment: Well, test it on a real device(s) to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to HStack, not to ScrollView

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it still shows with padding to the HStack. I have updated the question description.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).